# C# ASP.NET How to insert Eval value Repeater from Code-Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, repeater

In the repeater Design, I have something like this:

```
Text='<%# Eval("deposit") %>'
```

How do I insert the value from code-behind to "deposit" not using dataSource but by manually inserting string value?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblDeposit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("deposit") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: How you are populating repeater data. Can you share that code.

Comment: @MIdrees Hi, yes, Done thanks

Comment: I doubt if you can use repeater control without datasource, you have to assign some datasource, either it could be some DataTable, Array, List<T> etc...

Comment: For manually inserting string you can simply use List<T> as DataSource

Comment: @MIdrees Hi, I do have DataSource, but for that Deposit particular, I want to insert via code-behind

Comment: Can you share that DataSource related code, is it possible, can you add Deposit field with your DataSource, and then simply update the value in DataSource and it will reflect in repeater. Then you can also use ItemDataBound event to manually set string value for this field

Comment: Hi
Sorry could you please show me how to do the code? Sorry >< Dont know how

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemDataBound event, to bind field values manually. Like:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("lblDeposit") as Label;
        lbl.Text = "You Manual String Value";
    }
}
```

Attach this event to repeater in html markup:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
```